# When onRenderProcessUnresponsive is called?

Tags: webview, android-webview, android-webview-javascript

I'm wondering when the `WebViewRenderProcessClient.onRenderProcessUnresponsive()` method is triggered in the app using Android Webview and how to test it.

When I let my website hang by JS like `while(true) {}` the whole app becomes unresponsive (and Android OS suggests to terminate it) but `onRenderProcessUnresponsive` isn't getting triggered. Is there a way to gracefully catch and resolve conditions like that by our app code?

What could be the way to trigger `onRenderProcessUnresponsive` for tests ?